# Работа с json в c++

Tags: c++, json

Нужно чтобы в "Рейсы" было много рейсов
Типо ["Рейсы"] ["Рейс1],
["Рейсы"] ["Рейс2"] и тд при каждой новой записи
Ниже код записи в json файл
Пользуюсь библиотекой nlohman

```
 j["Рейсы"]["Рейс1"]=
         { 
                 "Номер рейса", reys1.GetReysID(),
                 "Количество зарезервированных мест", reys1.GetNumberOfSeats(),
                 "Общее количество мест", reys1.GetNumberOfSeats(),
                 "Время отправления" , reys1.GetReysTimeHours() ,":", reys1.GetReysTimeMins() ,
                 "Номер автобуса", Bus1.GetBusNumber(),
                 "Номер водителя", Driver.GetWorkerNumber(),
                 "Цена билета", reys1.GetPassPrice(),
                 "Пункт назначения", reys1.GetReysPlaceToGo()

        };

        fout << j;
```

Вот что мне записывает в файл

```
{ "Рейсы": { "Рейс2": [ "Номер рейса", 0, "Количество зарезервированных мест", 3, "Общее количество мест", 3, "Время отправления", 2, ":", 3, "Номер автобуса", 2, "Номер водителя", 3, "Цена билета", 2, "Пункт назначения", "Станица Кривянская" ] } }
```

Comment: Попробуйте другую библиотеку, например `json-c`.

Comment: Мне кажется дело не в библиотеке,а в моей криворукости
Скоро дедлайн,нет времени менять либу

Comment: Тогда приведите код `json` который должен быть на выходе.

Comment: Простите пожалуйста за столь безобразный вид.
Дальше Рейс 3 ,4 и тд.
```{
  "Рейсы": { "Рейс2": [ "Номер рейса", 0, "Количество зарезервированных мест", 3, "Общее количество мест", 3, "Время отправления", 2, ":", 3, "Номер автобуса", 2, "Номер водителя", 3, "Цена билета", 2, "Пункт назначения", "Станица Кривянская" ] },
           { "Рейс1": [ "Номер рейса", 0, "Количество зарезервированных мест", 3, "Общее количество мест", 3, "Время отправления", 2, ":", 3, "Номер автобуса", 2, "Номер водителя", 3, "Цена билета", 2, "Пункт назначения", "Станица Кривянская" ] }
}```

Comment: Это не `JSON`... У вас вместо json'a лабуда какая-то.

Comment: Минут через 10 я вам покажу как бы сделал я, с помощью библиотеки которую предложил раньше, у вас похоже проблемы с пониманием что такое json objects.

Comment: Я не знаю почему сайт так сделал,вот pastebin
https://pastebin.com/ewWqp1us

Comment: Json должен быть хотя бы таким: https://pastebin.com/ESg2K1P7

Comment: в json-c можно использовать" :" для ключа и значения ?
В nlohman нельзя
Можете скинуть код реализации вашего json?

Comment: @ヒミコ, если посмотреть на описание грамматики языка в [json.org](https://www.json.org/json-ru.html), то приведенный фрагмент вполне ей соответствует. Люди такие массивы на json не пишут, это верно. Но синтаксически тут все правильно.